# CSS3 Blur effect causes weird shadows on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got an html page where there is a DIV element covering the whole background with a background image, This DIV has also Blurred css3 effect on it.

When ever i hover on elements that sit above the blurred div i get alot of weird shadow bugs happening.

Chrome on OSX.

Attached screenshot:
[image]

Here is my background css:

```
#background {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-position: center  !important;
    background-attachment: center fixed;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -1;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 230px 75px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-filter 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.backgroundblur {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle, or link to this page?

Comment: Yeah it looks like you have some styles cascading that shouldn't be but can't say for sure without inspecting the dom. I can say that a cross-browser compatible alternative would be to make a copy of the background image that's blurred in photoshop and switch background images rather than using a CSS blur.

Comment: Page is not available online because its part of an extension im developing.

Comment: You can download and install it here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/beautiful-new-tab/kjhogahkpddegccjgcnlhfocgcgjjkjp?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon

Comment: I've checked about the cascading, thing is Once you change something in DOM, height, color, move the screen size, the effect goes away.

Comment: I have the same issue on Chrome OS X (Build 38). Blur filter creates weird overlays.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could load your HTML with this sample. But I guess that problem is in #background element, coz  there's shadow applied on it, and it look like your content is in that element also.

I tried to produce similar effect on     `<http://jsfiddle.net/zlajaa1/4s941ewz/>`    . Problem here is negative z-index value. So maybe you can try to play with that property also.

For more help, attach HTML with this please.