# Strange shadowed boxes randomly appearing - CSS error?

Tags: css, shadow

On [this website](http://www.readyto.watch/), on Chrome, when hovering or clicking the "EXPLORE" button, I am getting a lot of weird shadowed boxes popping up in random places. What could this be from? I have inspected the elements but it doesn't seem that any of them could be causing these.

A screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was with blur: the background was using a blur filter and this created weird shadows. I am not sure why and how this was happening, though. I removed the blur and just blurred the actual BG image in Photoshop.
It seems like I was encountering the same problem as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170986/css3-blur-effect-causes-weird-shadows-on-hover).

Answer (score 1):

In your stylesheet, I'm seeing some box-shadows (and it looks like box-shadows, not text-shadows). And they only appear on hover so chances are, when you inspected your elements, you didn't inspect them on their hover states.

Regardless, go in to your stylesheets and search for `box-shadow` and set it to none.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your site in Firefox or Chrome
2. Reproduce the error
3. right click on the weird shadow box and select inspect this
4. look for a box-shadow in your inspector and disable by clicking off the checkbox
5. If it worked, give yourself a cookie! You're a master debugger

Answer (score 0):

There's a `.tooltip` that's being loaded via js. There was 18 instances of it being called in the `custom.js` file. If you don't want it, you can just stop calling it from within this file.

Alternatively, there are 27 instances of .tooltip in your css file. You can go through an remove them or just add `.tooltip {border-style: hidden;}` in you html file and it should remove the border.

[EDIT]

I took a screenshot of the Chrome inspector:

[image]

You can see the element being added via js when you hover over the page down chevron. You can get rid of the tooltip altogether, or inspect the `.tooltip`, `.fade`, `.top` or `.in` css to see which one of these items is creating the offending box.

You should be able to make this stop just using css. My understanding is, if you put the css directly in the html it should trump whatever is in your css file if you don't want to change the file itself. HTH

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I don't see how the tooltips are causing this border: that CSS rule doesn't change anything. Also, the weird border doesn't appear on Safari.

Comment: That's just a tooltip element... It's supposed to be over the chevron. It's not creating the box. Disabling the tooltips doesn't change anything, neither does removing box-shadows from my stylesheets.

Comment: It looks like you fixed the issue - would you please post what you did to correct the problem so others searching might learn from this post? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure. It turns out the issue was with blur: the background was using a blur filter and this created weird shadows. I am not sure why and how this was happening, though. I removed the blur and just blurred the actual BG image in Photoshop.

Comment: Seems like it was the same problem as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170986/css3-blur-effect-causes-weird-shadows-on-hover).